# How to set attribute value of HTML tag by an array in Alpine Js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am new in alpine js, I am trying to fill five star like rating(2.3 out of 5 means 2 star full fill and 3rd one filled by 30%, rest should be empty) while I set offset value like in the given below code then it fills all star by 1st value of percentage:['60', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%'] while it should fill 1st star 60% rest by 0% but it fills all as 60% :

```
            <template x-for="(offset, index) in percentage" :key="index">
            <svg class="h-6 w-6 " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                <defs>
                    <linearGradient id="grad">
                        <stop x-bind:offset="offset" :key="index" stop-color="yellow"/>
                        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="gray"/>
                    </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <path fill="url(#grad)" d="M9.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.07 3.292a1 1 0 00.95.69h3.462c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-2.8 2.034a1 1 0 00-.364 1.118l1.07 3.292c.3.921-.755 1.688-1.54 1.118l-2.8-2.034a1 1 0 00-1.175 0l-2.8 2.034c-.784.57-1.838-.197-1.539-1.118l1.07-3.292a1 1 0 00-.364-1.118L2.98 8.72c-.783-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h3.461a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.07-3.292z"/>
            </svg> 
        </template>
```

Comment: _"how to set offset value in Alpine js"_ what do you mean by offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`x-bind` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind) at `offset` attribute to set it dynamically. Inside an Alpine.js directive we can use regular JS code, so we can append the percent sign after the percent value using template literals. Furthermore, we need to generate a unique `id` for each `linearGradient` definition, otherwise the first would be applied to each of the SVG element.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{percentage: [20, 40, 60, 80, 100]}">
  <template x-for="element in percentage">
    <svg style="height: 20px; width: 20px;" class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient :id="`grad-${element}`">
          <stop :offset="`${element}%`" stop-color="yellow" />
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="gray" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <path :fill="`url(#grad-${element})`"
        d="M9.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.07 3.292a1 1 0 00.95.69h3.462c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-2.8 2.034a1 1 0 00-.364 1.118l1.07 3.292c.3.921-.755 1.688-1.54 1.118l-2.8-2.034a1 1 0 00-1.175 0l-2.8 2.034c-.784.57-1.838-.197-1.539-1.118l1.07-3.292a1 1 0 00-.364-1.118L2.98 8.72c-.783-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h3.461a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.07-3.292z" />
    </svg>
  </template>
</div>
```

Note: remove the `style="height: 20px; width: 20px;"`, I added it only for SO code snippet.